# Creating an ldap service in symfony3

Tags: symfony

I am building my first symfony app. It will need to do lookups in LDAP, but *NOT* as part of a security/firewall item.  (all access is anon)

My thought is I would use the `Toyota\Component\Ldap\Core\Manager` and create a service.

In services, I have defined

```
app.ldap:
  class: Toyota\Component\Ldap\Core\Manager
  arguments: [ldap]
```

The issue is I am not sure how to pass in the arguments (hostname, bind_dn, password, etc). I would like to keep them inside of `config.yml` or other file.

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: ldap is really an array of options, I can make it work if it is a single option.